# Windows encrypted files is readable

Tags: windows, encryption

When I encrypt a file and send it through the network to another computer it is not readable just like it should be. Same, if I share it with a memory stick it stays unreadable for the other computers.

When I send it to a friend through Facebook they can read it, and the file is no longer green (encrypted).

Why is the file no longer encrypted?
Is it some way sent the decrypted way, even if I close the file and no longer keep it opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes when you move your file to other devices, the prompt will ask to decrypt before you move to the device. if so, the file will be decrypted. just keep say yes to the prompt so fill will remain the same